# get today events from mysql using fullCalendar

Tags: mysql

i have events mysql table - structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `date_start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_start` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_end` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `allday` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

i'm trying to write mysql query to get events that occuring today

**example**

event start in 3/13/2014 and end in 3/30/2014

event start in 3/19/2014 and end in 3/20/2014

today is 18 i want to get events occuring today, that's mean event 1 and 2 because they occure during today

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
SELECT *
FROM `events`
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN `date_start` AND `date_end`
```

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acd70/1

Comment: I like this better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want events that happen 'today' (which would need to be set dynamically) you could just check for dates before and after 'today':

```
SELECT * FROM `events`
WHERE (date_start > '2014-03-17 23:59:59') AND date_end < '2014-03-19 00:00:00')
```